# I want to change style according to window width using states

Tags: reactjs, styles, state, window-width

```
style={window.innerWidth<='750 px' ?{myStyle}:{}}
```

can anyone help me in this?
I want to set the style according to window width.
`myStyle` is a state.

Answer (score 1):

Hey here is a hook I wrote awhile back for getting the window dimensions then you can just use the width from the hook in your style tag with a ternary operator to display different styles

```
function getWindowDimensions() {
  const { innerWidth: width, innerHeight: height } = window;
  return {
    width,
    height,
  };
}

/**
 * @returns {object} {width, height}
 */

export default function useWindowDimensions() {
  const [windowDimensions, setWindowDimensions] = useState(
    getWindowDimensions()
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleResize() {
      setWindowDimensions(getWindowDimensions());
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  }, []);

  return windowDimensions;
}
```

usage

```
const Component = () => {
  const {width, height} = useWindowDimensions()

  return <div style ={width > 750 ? {Place >750 styles here} : {Place < 750 styles here} }></div>
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do that is using a custom hook. This hook can get the current window `width` and `height` when the window size is changed.

The event listener is registered when the component is mounted to update the state and safely removed when it is unmounted.

```
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

// hook to get window size dynamically
const useWindowSize = () => {
    // Initialize state with undefined width/height so server and client renders match
    // Learn more here: https://joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration/
    const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState({
        width: undefined,
        height: undefined
    });

    useEffect(() => {
        // only execute all the code below in client side
        if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
            // Handler to call on window resize
            function handleResize() {
                // Set window width/height to state
                setWindowSize({
                    width: window.innerWidth,
                    height: window.innerHeight
                });
            }

            // Add event listener
            window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);

            // Call handler right away so state gets updated with initial window size
            handleResize();

            // Remove event listener on cleanup
            return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
        }
    }, []); // Empty array ensures that effect is only run on mount
    return windowSize;
};

export default useWindowSize;
```

This solution works perfectly with server rendering as well. Import the `useWindowSize` hook into the component you want and use the size as you want.

```
import useWindowSize from '/path/to/hooks/useWindowSize' 

const MyComp = () => {
  const size = useWindowSize();

  return <div style={style={size.width<='750 px' ?{myStyle}:{}}}></div>;
};

export default MyComp;
```